# Sencha binding exceeding Scheduler cycle limit due to duplicate IDs upsetting sort routine

Tags: extjs

I've inherited code for a complex UI which has started to fail under Sencha 6.5. It is using inherited viewmodel binding and is reasonably complex.

Trying to debug through the Scheduler, I've found that its `scheduledCount` value is being increased by two of my bindings calling `scheduleItem()`. However these bindings are added to the scheduler early in the processing with IDs that duplicate IDs already in the scheduler. They're not the same instance otherwise things may work. They look like clones.

The Scheduler's `sort()` routine sees these items and ignores them, believing them to be already sorted. So I end up with 95 items in the scheduler's item list, but only 93 items in its work queue. The `notify()` method cycles around the 93 item queue trying to find its two items to work on an fails to find them. This repeats until the `cycleLimit` is exceeded and the two scheduled items are never processed.

Next time the user presses a button another two items are added to the scheduler, so now it has 97 items in its item list and 93 items in its work queue. And so on.

I suspect the bug is in the cloning, but it's so hard to find out which bit of code is doing this!

Has anyone seen this before? Is there an easy solution or workaround?

Comment: Can you make some working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) ?

Comment: Not easily. It's a huge application. I've not been able to work out what causes the issue so I can try to stop doing it - hence wondering if anyone had seen it before. (Also deadlines as ever loom!)

Comment: I'm guessing at auto-inherited ViewModel state going through bindings. I've removed two of these from the system by passing the change through explicit events, but not solved the problem. Though I seem to have reduced it to only adding one item per iteration not two.

Comment: If the ids are consistent, you might try putting a conditional breakpoint for those ids in the constructor of the binding to see what is causing them to be (re)constructed.

Comment: I'll have to do a run through. Another idea was a condition breakpoint on the addItem method to detect it being inserted, though I didn't get far with similar before.

Comment: It's calling into `add()` because the `sort()` method sees in item that has `item.scheduler` falsy. This is coming from `notify` not the `sortItem` callback, so the item is already in the scheduler's items collection. (I'll recheck that). The question is how this happened. Scheduler's `add` method sets `scheduler`. So either something cleared it on the item, or something accessed the scheduler's items collection to insert it without calling add. I do wish this code properly encapsulated the scheduler's state!

Comment: Indeed, this line at the top of `notify` traps indicating that there is an item in the list that does not have scheduler set. `if(me.items.items.some(x => !x.scheduler)) debugger`

Comment: The offending items are all instances of `Ext.app.bind.LinkStub`. They have `destroyed = isDestroyed = true`.  They don't appear to be currently scheduled. Trapping inside the notify loop just before it hits cycle count I have one item for which `scheduler=null` with `id=76`.  I have two items with `scheduled=true`, one `id=56, destroyed=undefined`, same again `id=55`.  Iterating over the list in order looking for `id == 56` I have two items, the first destroyed and unscheduled, the second scheduled.  I'm beginning to suspect the destroy method in LinkStub.

Comment: We're trying to work around the problem, though I've seen it making LinkStubs into child component ViewModels even though the child component and its view model have no references to the values! I have seen what looks like a mistake in `RootStub.set()` in which it passes an Object to `Object.hasOwnProperty()` where I think it should be passing the string `key`. Correcting this mistake did not solve the issue.

Comment: We have worked around the issue by moving to old fashioned events and setting properties in the Controllers.